# React, useCallback re-call again even if dependency did not change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, memoization

I'm using `useCallback` to memoize a function, I wrote 2 functions, `formatCounter` and `formatCounter2` and added `useCallback` to the functions with dependencies of `counter` and `counter2`.

When `onClick` function is called, the `counter` variable has changed but `formatCounter2` called, but why? As I understand it needs to be called only when the dependency changes (`counter2`) and it does not change.

```
function App() {
 const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
 const [counter2, setCounter2] = React.useState(0);

 const onClick = React.useCallback(()=>{
   setCounter(prevState => ++prevState)
 },[]);
 
 const onClickSecond = React.useCallback(()=>{
   setCounter2(prevState => ++prevState)
 },[]);
 
 const formatCounter = React.useCallback((counterVal)=> {
 console.log('formatCounter Called')
  return `The counter value is ${counterVal}`;
},[counter])

 const formatCounter2 = React.useCallback((counterVal2)=> {
  console.log('formatCounterTwo Called')

  return `The counter value2 is ${counterVal2}`;
},[counter2])

const objMemo = React.useMemo(()=> {
    console.log('obj memo is')
    return {
    a:counter>2?'counter is bigger than 2': 'counter is less than 2'
  }
},[counter])
 return (
   <div className="App">
     <div>{formatCounter(counter)}</div>
     <div>{formatCounter2(counter2)}</div>
     <button onClick={onClick}>
       Increment
     </button>
      <button onClick={onClickSecond}>
       Increment2
     </button>
     <p>{objMemo.a}</p>
   </div>
 );
}
```

[link to code](https://jsfiddle.net/cjw3p61L/27/)

Comment: incorrect, useCallback memoizes the function and will return the same "function" instance on rerender (if nothing is changed in deps array) instead of returning the new "function" on each render. So "formatCounter2" is preserver, in memory it is the same "function" still, but due to rerender it is still executed. But not recreated. If you remove both counter and counter2 from depsArray of your functions - they will still be called in same way. Both. On every rerender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useCallback` memoizes the function reference. But you're calling the format functions (both) in the render method. So what you're actually seeing is the inner function being called.

Maybe out of curiosity you can check the *reference* to the function you're memoizing. There you will see that the reference is not changing.

To check this I usually do:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('formatCounter reference changed!', formatCounter);
  }, [formatCounter]);
```

You will see that it logs for when `counter` changes but not for when `counter2` changes.